# Using powershell to add an operation with template parameters to an azure api

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-api-management

When attempting to add an operation to an Azure Api Management Api, using the powershell cmdlt `New-AzureRmApiManagementOperation`, the command returns the uninformative response: `ValidationError: One or more fields contain incorrect values`.

The command does run successfully when the operation's `UrlTemplate` contains no parameters (ie url fragments in curly braces), but does not handle invocations where they are present.

This works as expected:

```
New-AzureRmApiManagementOperation -Context $context -ApiId $aid -OperationId $oid -Name $name -Method $method -UrlTemplate '/all'
```

But this doesn't:

```
New-AzureRmApiManagementOperation -Context $context -ApiId $aid -OperationId $oid -Name $name -Method $method -UrlTemplate '/{id}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the information provided [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/new-azurermapimanagementoperation?view=azurermps-5.6.0) is somewhat inaccurate. The `TemplateParameters` is not optional when parameters are present, and is very much not being automatically generated.

The array of objects of type `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Models.PsApiManagementParameter` must be present, and for each parameter in the url template it must contain an element with `Name` with the same value as the parameters value, and `Type` being a member of some enumeration, presumably matching some swagger definitions.

The following code generates such an array from a template string:

```
$tparam = Select-String "{([^}]+)}" -input $template -AllMatches |
    Foreach { $_.matches } |
    Foreach {
        $p = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Models.PsApiManagementParameter
        $p.Name = $_.Groups[1].Value
        $p.Type = "string"
        return $p
    }
```

It can be followed by:

```
New-AzureRmApiManagementOperation -Context $context -ApiId $aid -OperationId $oid -Name $name -Method $method -UrlTemplate $template -TemplateParameters $tparam
```